# how to recompile smarty template after edit of template files?

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty

I have made changes to some of my template files in CodeIgniter and now some of my pages show blank white content.

I just read many forum posts even in the Smarty website but can't find the exact reason why it happens.just find out smarty template needs to be compiled after each edit. but I don't know how to do that.

I just changed some meta tags in the header.tpl but it shows blank pages in admin.

Comment: smarty does that automatically afaik, but it does have a cache and compile directory. perhaps clean those out.

Comment: i dont really know what to do, can u help alex?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer to this on my environment (Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS, Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu), PHP 5.5.9 and Smarty 2.6.3)

Had to change the permissions such that all the files and folders of my Smarty application were writeable by the apache2 user -

```sh
cd /var/www/html/
chmod -R www-data:www-data *
```

After running the above commands, template changes were instantly avaialble after a page refresh.